# A question about the article 'You can't hear the shape of a drum'

Tags: group-theory, analysis, representation-theory, spectral-theory, inverse-problems

I have read the article http://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/425S11/Drum-Gordon-Webb.pdf, , where Gordon and Webb describe in a simple a way the contruction of a pair of isospectral but non isometric plane domains.

At pag $52$ they mention the group $G$ used by Brooks and Buser in order to construct isospectral surfaces and they consider a particular set of generators of $G$ made by three elements, without specifying who is this group and these generators.

My question is this: is this $G$ the group $SL(3,2)$? Are the generators $\alpha=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
\end{array}\right),$
$\beta=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
\end{array}\right),$
$\gamma=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&1&1\\
\end{array}\right) ?$

Comment: Everything that i stold about $G$, including the Cayley graph, supports this assumption (though I'd guess that their $\alpha$ is your $\gamma$)

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen, thanks for your answer! Can you explain me why do you say that from the Cayley graphs it can be deduced that $G$ is very probably $SL(3,2)$? Why my $\alpha$ should be their $\gamma$? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: In http://www.math.ru.nl/~heckman/RS.Scriptie.pdf, section five explains a counterexample from Buser, Conway and Doyle (reference 4 at the end). This counterexample uses $PSL(\mathbb{F}_2^3)$, so the projective version of $SL(3,2)$. I don't currently have the time to see if this is the same counterexample, though.

Comment: Dumb question on my part, perhaps, but these aren't really Cayley graphs per se, are they?  Just compact ways of encoding the permutations represented by $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$...